# Help! Kentia palm is sad :(

Tags: plant-care, palm, kentia

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O2GA.jpg

[EDIT] More pictures requested of the underside of leaves: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFjlI.jpg

We're having troubles with our Kentia palm after a month in its new home. It has all manner of maladies, and we're not totally sure what's behind it. Some of the lower leaves are browning/yellowing, some leaves have darkened/blacked tips, and we're finding spots and holes on various leaves.

There are lots of possible factors and we're having difficulty isolating the issues... possible concerns:

- We're in San Francisco and with heat waves + poor air quality, so we've been running the air purifier a lot (and the occasional fan), which may be drying out the palm
- We don't have a humidifier in the room. We're considering getting one for the palm. We do mist the plant regularly.
- It's somewhat close to a south-facing window so we're suspecting that it's getting too much light as well. Could that be possible? Would be good to confirm this as this would affect how we lay out the room.
- We're worried we may have overwatered it. We're doing it based off of dryness of the top couple inches of the soil, which ends up being every 2 weeks.
- We're also not ruling out possible bug issues. We've had a bunch of fungus gnats in the apartment and found spider mites on another plant the other day. We do use mosquito bits, neem oil, and gnat traps, etc, and we have been inspecting this palm closely and not finding any pests. Upon checking the soil we did find millipedes/centipedes/sowbugs, but research tells us that these are not harmful for the plant...

Help! We love this tree and want to quickly get it to a better condition before it's too late.

Comment: Hi Calvin, without another picture it's hard to give you a good answer.  Can you take a picture with your phone at low resolution and then upload it? Use the edit button and the image icon to add a closeup of the underside of the leaf.

Comment: Hi @kevinsky -- I've edited the post with a link to more pictures as requested. Thank you!